# pandas confusion with multiindex columns loc and get_level_values

Tags: python, pandas

Please forgive me if I do not provide a minimal working example but I cannot reproduce one (I tried for about one hour).

**Given following index:**

```
df_original.columns    

MultiIndex(levels=[['ft', 'load', 's0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8'], ['260', '280', '603', 'buffer', 'pH', 'salt', 'salt_concentration', 'sample_volume', 'volume']],
       labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]],
       names=['steps', 'data'])
```

I would like to extract the data from the multi index by regex matching:

```
mask = gr.columns.get_level_values(1).str.match(r'^\d{3}')
df = gr.loc[:,mask].copy()
```

yield the desired output.

**When I look at:**

```
df.get_level_values(1)
```

everything looks as expected.

```
Index(['260', '280', '603', '603', '260', '280', '603', '260', '280', '603',
   '260', '280', '603', '260', '280', '603', '260', '280', '603', '260',
   '280', '603', '260', '280', '603', '260', '280', '603', '260', '280',
   '603', '260', '280'],
  dtype='object', name='data')
```

**However**

```
df.columns
```

still looks like the original dataframe `df_original`

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['ft', 'load', 's0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8'], ['260', '280', '603', 'buffer', 'pH', 'salt', 'salt_concentration', 'sample_volume', 'volume']],
       labels=[[1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]],
       names=['steps', 'data'])
```

**The point of all this is an odd behavior:**

I would like to add information to the sliced (and copied) dataframe. I do this by looping:

```
steps = df.columns.get_level_values('steps').unique().tolist()


for step in steps:
    df[step, 'a.pH'] = 1 
    df[step, 'a.salt_concentration'] = 2 
    df[step, 'a.buffer'] = 3
```

**Everything fine until now:**

```
df.stack('steps')
```

After the stack operation. All excluded columns are visible again (excluded via:
`gr.columns.get_level_values(1).str.match(r'\d{3}')`)

Why is that so and how can I avoid this odd behavior ?

EDIT:

the original data (parts of it): https://pastebin.com/WLjP2ws3

A workaround is to use `df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` afterwards

Comment: Is there any way we can get the original values of your dataframe? Maybe `df.head()`

Comment: of `df_original` ?

Comment: Yes. I meant df_original

Comment: added a link to pastebin

Comment: See jezrael's answer in the target. There is a `remove_unusued_levels` method in newer versions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was sitting here since 6 hours due to that issue.